# Sending AMQP Telemetry to Azure Event Hub not using TLS encryption

Tags: azure, encryption, azure-eventhub

Is it possible to send AMQP packets/telemetry to Azure Event Hub not using TLS encryption?

The reason I want to do this, is to see exactly what a non-encrypted AMQP packet looks like.

I have tried the following code (see **amqpTransSetting.UseSslStreamSecurity = false**, but it still encrypts the communication.

```
        var amqpTransSetting = new AmqpTransportSettings();
        amqpTransSetting.UseSslStreamSecurity = false;

        var cs = @"Endpoint=sb://companyname-ns.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=EventHubPublisher;SharedAccessKey=84EHa5NNllnZBzH5ksogvNfhMWtIokdTdjxXXXXXXX=";

        var builder = new ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder(cs)
                    {
                        TransportType = TransportType.Amqp,
                    };

        var client = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(builder.ToString(), "companyname-eh");

        int sentCount = sendCount;
        string infoText;

        for (int i = 0; i < sendCount; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                if (MessageType.Text == "Fake Sensor")
                {
                    infoText = "Sent using AMQP protocol";
                }
                else
                {
                    infoText = "Sent using AMQP protocol";
                }

                Random rnd = new Random();
                int intTemp = rnd.Next(15, 25);
                int intHum = rnd.Next(50, 80);

                var e = new Event
                {
                    MessageType = MessageType.Text,
                    Temp = intTemp,
                    Humidity = intHum,
                    Location = Location.Text,
                    Room = Room.Text,
                    Info = infoText
                };

                var serializedString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(e);
                var data = new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializedString))
                {
                    PartitionKey = rnd.Next(6).ToString()
                };

                // Set user properties if needed
                data.Properties.Add("Type", "Telemetry_" + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());



                await client.SendAsync(data).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error on send: " + exp.Message);
                sentCount--;
            }
```

Comment: I would suggest asking a new question about what you want to achieve (or revising this one). From the comments below it sounds like you might be happy with the HTTP interface (not that I've ever used it). If you expect a large number of embedded devices but not particularly high volume  from any individual device (ie a few per second per device is fine) it should be lighter weight AND there's a limit on the number of AMQP connections per hub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSL/TLS connection is mandatory for accessing to all entities in the Service Bus (queues, topics/subscriptions and event hubs). You can't connect without it.

Paolo.

Comment: Thanks Paolo. I was beginning to see that this was the case....but I really need to see what a raw AMQP telemetry packet looks like. As I need to manually create one on top of AMQP so I can then send using a small embedded device, without the need to use a large library, which the device does not have space for. Any suggestions on how I can do this? Is reading the specification the only way forward? That is a large time investment I am trying to avoid :-(

Comment: I meant create a AMQP packet on top of TCP

Comment: AMQP protocol is quite complex and the only way is to use a library or write a new one reading the AMQP 1.0 specification. Of course there is a lighter protocol like MQTT and related libraries are lighter than AMQP libraries. However, MQTT isn't supported natively on Service Bus (but you can wait for Azure IoT Suite after Build 2015) but you can host an MQTT broker inside an Azure Worker Role or Virtual Machine. Remember that MQTT hasn't support for request/reply pattern as AMQP (like correlation and replyTo) and you have to implement it over MQTT using well designed topics (it's possible)

Comment: Just a question : your example uses Azure SDK but you are speaking about embedded devices. What are your constraints ?

Comment: Size is the constraint, I cannot use a library. The example is to see what the AMQP packet would look like, so i can try and create it it manually on top of TCP. I recently chatted with the Event Hub team and they said they will not be supporting MQTT. I need direct communication with event hub, the solution requires high performance and scale.

Comment: I do not require pub/sub with topics or anything like that. I just need to send telemetry with AMQP. This should not be too complex, and I was hoping I just need to create the application layer data on top of TCP correctly.

Comment: You can avoid to use a full implemented library like Qpid Proton C of course but you need to develop your own library reading the standard. I read all the standard and it isn't so simple to implement. However, in software all is possible :-) good luck !

Comment: Thanks for all your help Paolo. I might see if I can find a AMQP server, so I can send to it without the SSL requirement....that way I can perform the packet trace without encryption and see what telemetry looks like.