# How can I use AMQP protocol over TLS when communicating with Azure Event Hubs

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I am sending some data from a field gateway to an eventhub. I am concerned about security of the data sent. Righ now I am using the following code and data is going to eventhub. I wanted to know if data is being encryped behind the sceens by the sendSync method, or I need to add some code to encrypt the data before sending

```
EventData sendEvent = new EventData(payloadBytes);
EventHubClient ehClient = EventHubClient.createFromConnectionStringSync(connStr.toString());        
ehClient.sendSync(sendEvent);
```

I am new to data security so any input would be a great help...Thankyou!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All data is send using TLS by default. It is mandatory for using the event hub. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/event-hubs-authentication-and-security-model-overview/ (Devices sending data)

So, you do not need any additional code.

See also [Sending AMQP Telemetry to Azure Event Hub not using TLS encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29665965/sending-amqp-telemetry-to-azure-event-hub-not-using-tls-encryption)

Comment: Thank you Peter Bons. The documentation says " To prevent an attacker from eavesdropping and stealing the token, the communication between the device and the Event Hub MUST occur over an encrypted channel. " I didn't know if this meant we had to implement it or it was already implemented. Thanks for clarifying.